# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog exit button

Tags: java

If I had a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, how do I make the program exit when the user presses the red x?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World!");
```

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. You have to use showOptionDialog and customise it the way you want (ie to show only the OK button) and then check the returned state, if it's CLOSED_OPTION, then the dialog was closed by not using one of the options ;)

Comment: Thank you for your idea, i'll look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a part of code which should be useful:

```
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit?", "Confirm Exit",
                                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                            System.exit(0);

                    }
                });
```

You can also use JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help!